# angular flex layout grid system

Tags: angular, grid-system, angular-flex-layout

[image]

I want to make the screen like the attached image, but getting some issues. My code is working fine for Small devices and Large devices, but for Medium devices, it's not working fine. So can anyone look into my code and help me to solve this issue?
Actually, I am a little confused with the Flex layout grid system. It's very easy to achieve this in Bootstrap, but I want the same in Flex Layout.

```
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign.lg="start center"
     fxLayoutAlign.xs="center center" fxLayoutAlign.sm="center center">

  <div fxFlex="25%" fxFlex.md="50%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%" fxLayout.md="row"
       class="pading_card">
    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
          A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
          bred for hunting.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>

  <div fxFlex="25%" fxFlex.md="50%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%" class="pading_card">
    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
          A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
          bred for hunting.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>

  <div fxFlex="25%" fxFlex.md="50%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%" class="pading_card">
    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
          A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
          bred for hunting.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>

  <div fxFlex="25%" fxFlex.md="50%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%" class="pading_card">
    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
          A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
          bred for hunting.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please attempt the code yourself first, if you have issues feel free to ask for help but you cannot expect others to write your code for you- this is a QnA site.

Comment: How can you get to know I put my problem here without attempting by myself? @Anth12

Comment: Because you have not posted the code! If you have attempted, then please post the code you are having trouble with and describe any particular issues so that others may assist.

Comment: Please look into my code. First time I am asking question on this website. So I did not know the rules that how should I ask questions here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-md="column"  fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <div fxLayout.gt-md="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column"  fxLayoutGap="10px" fxFlex="100"  fxFlex.gt-md="50">
          <div fxFlex.lt-md="50" fxFlex.lt-sm="100" >1</div>
          <div fxFlex.lt-md="50" fxFlex.lt-sm="100" >2</div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout.gt-md="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxFlex="100"   fxFlex.gt-md="50">
          <div fxFlex.lt-md="50" fxFlex.lt-sm="100" >3</div>
          <div fxFlex.lt-md="50" fxFlex.lt-sm="100" >4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## HTML

```
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">
  <div fxLayout.gt-md="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="50">
    <div fxFlex.lt-md="50" fxFlex.lt-sm="100">
      <mat-card class="example-card">
        <mat-card-header>
          <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
          <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>
            The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
            A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
            bred for hunting.
          </p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
          <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex.lt-md="50" fxFlex.lt-sm="100">
      <mat-card class="example-card">
        <mat-card-header>
          <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
          <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>
            The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
            A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
            bred for hunting.
          </p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
          <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout.gt-md="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="50">
    <div fxFlex.lt-md="50" fxFlex.lt-sm="100">
      <mat-card class="example-card">
        <mat-card-header>
          <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
          <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>
            The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
            A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
            bred for hunting.
          </p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
          <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex.lt-md="50" fxFlex.lt-sm="100">
      <mat-card class="example-card">
        <mat-card-header>
          <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
          <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>
            The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
            A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
            bred for hunting.
          </p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
          <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.example-card {

}

.example-header-image {
  background-image: url('https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.pading_card {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: doesn't wrap with lots of items

Comment: @irhetoric please use the approved answer, given above. It will work.